# How to serialize/deserialize polars datatypes?

Tags: python-polars

I need to save/read polars datatypes to/from a text file ( json, csv ...)
I am wondering what is the best way to to it.

I have tried:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(schema={'a': pl.Int64, 'b': pl.List(pl.Float64)})
json.loads(json.dumps(df.schema)) # TypeError: Object of type DataTypeClass is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: You should include the error you get when calling `json.dumps`. Here it is in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/thomasaarholt/21ceb094997f25055eb5c434085ce4af).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way:

```py
def parse_composite_dtype(dtype) -> str:
    if dtype.is_nested:
        return f"{pl.datatypes.convert.DataTypeMappings.DTYPE_TO_FFINAME[dtype.base_type()]}[{parse_composite_dtype(dtype.inner)}]"
    else:
        return pl.datatypes.convert.DataTypeMappings.DTYPE_TO_FFINAME[dtype]
def schema_to_string(schema) -> str:
    return json.dumps({k: parse_composite_dtype(v) for k, v in df.schema.items()})

def schema_from_string(schema: str):
    return {k: pl.datatypes.convert.dtype_short_repr_to_dtype(v) for k, v in json.loads(schema).items()}
```

On your data this gives:

```py
schema_to_string(df.schema) == '{"a":"i64","b":"list[f64]"}'
```

and

```py
schema_from_string(schema_to_string(df.schema)) == df.schema
```